# Отправка формы при выборе select

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, select

Есть такой html

```
<form action="/config/lang" method="POST" >
    <select class="select_send_ajax selectpicker">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>                 
    </select>
 </form>
```

И js который отвечает за обработку

```
$('.select_send_ajax').on('change', function () {
    this.form.submit();
});


$('form').submit(function(event) { //Отправка всех форм        
      console.log(123);
      event.preventDefault();
}
```

Когда выбираю что-то в `select` то форма отправляется сразу хотя мы запретили отправку форм. Необходимо чтобы при выборе `select` попыталась отправиться форма, но так как мы ей запретили выведется только `123` в консоли

Comment: и где же вы запретили отправлять формы ?

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, `return;`

Comment: гуглить "js прервать отправку формы" пробовали? Вопрос уже тысячу раз обсужден.

Comment: Разъясню - `return;` не отменяет отправку формы.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko , это делает `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Тогда почему при отправки формы с обычной кнопки это срабатывает, а когда пытаюсь отправить так `this.form.submit();`  при выборе `select` то процесс не останавливается?

Comment: @Vasily Koshelev, исправил обработчик, но все так же не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 22.)*

```
$(this.form).submit();
```

```js
$('.select_send_ajax').on('change', function() {
  $(this.form).submit();
});

$('form').submit(function(event) { //Отправка всех форм       
  console.log(123);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/config/lang" method="POST">
  <select class="select_send_ajax selectpicker">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: При попытке отправить alert 'submit!' и страница все-равно перезагружается

Comment: @r.mcreal Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: @r.mcreal И поставьте закрывающую скобку `)` в `$('form').submit(...`.

Comment: да все хорошо работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @r.mcreal Пожалуйста. Успехов!